# Getting unexpected CORS error with socket.io and React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, sockets

I don't know what else to try

My server:

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app)
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());
const socketio = require('socket.io')
const io = socketio(server);



io.on("connect", socket => {
    console.log("hello");

    socket.on("welcome ", (e) => {
        console.log(e)
    })


});


const port = 8081;

server.listen(port, () => console.log(`listen on port ${port}`))
```

in app react

```
import io from "socket.io-client";
let socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8081");
 socket.emit("welcome", "connected");
```

react run port 3000

nodejs run port 8081

but everything I try throws error.

Comment: ... what's the error?

Comment: Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8081/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NPJYJYE' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
polling-xhr.js:268 GET http://localhost:8081/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NPJYJYE net::ERR_FAILED

Comment: Are you aware that Javascript isn't allowed to access other website? Like, you can't connect to `chasebank.com` for example. (unless *you're* chasebank.com)

Comment: so how could I connect my sockets with react-app and a nodejs server? since react opens at 3000 and my server has to choose a different port

Comment: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client/issues/1379